# When I try to run my app in the emulator, it is showing an error

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-ide

[The error is shown when I run my code in Android Studio. I want to run my app in the emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhssX.png).

[This is showing when I want to select the device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltR9j.png).

I want to run my code in a verchular device.

Error:

> Installation did not succeed. 
> The application could not be installed: INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK
>
> List of APK files:
>
> [0] 'C:\Users\hp\Downloads\notes\app\build\intermediates\apk\debug\app-debug.apk' 
> The application's minSdkVersion is newer than the device API level. 
> Retry 
> Failed to launch an application on all devices

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and take the appropriate [action](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78174184/edit). Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is "verchular device"? Do you mean "virtual device" , "vertical device" or "vehicular device"? In any case, can you elaborate?

Comment: Possibly you have to set your min SDK Api level below the api level of your virtual device.